# what is the cause of 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException'?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

Exceptions:
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

```
    public static IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    private void GetScoreData()
    {
        if (settings.Contains(dataItem2.Name))
        {
            this.textBlock2.Text = settings[dataItem2.Name].ToString();
        }
        else 
        {
            settings.Add(dataItem2.Name, "N/A");
            this.textBlock2.Text = "N/A";
        }
        settings.Save();
    }
```

now in the other page

i am updating its value  by doing this

ScorePage.settings["MyKey"] = moves.ToString();

so everytime i restart my emulator and run my project this exception comes. 
any reason why?

Comment: How about you look at the message of the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isolated storage in the emulator is not persisted after you close it.

Reference: [Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563%28v=vs.92%29.aspx): (see features)

Isolated storage is available while the emulator is running. Data in isolated storage does not persist after the emulator closes. This includes files stored in a local database, as these files reside in isolated storage.
I suggest you to use site settings over application settings.
One more thing, dont worry the windows phone is persistent.(only the emulator is not!)

Answer (score 1):

After restarting the emulator (or reinstallign the app), the contents on IsolatedStorage will be deleted.  If you're trying to update a setting, first check that the key exists.

Showing the line where the exception occurs and the exact text of the exception will also help with identifying the issue.

Comment: look GetScoreData() method is in my "main page" wherein i am checking the key's existence now this page adds the key if it does'nt exists(else block) then only i am proceeding to my other page where i am updating it without checking. Is it still a problem?

& the exception is also not reproducible. it did'nt came this time when i uninstalled & reinstalled my app. Any Idea...why?